# R devtools: package documentation on first page of the manual

Tags: r, documentation, devtools, roxygen2, manual

How do I make `devtools::build_manual` put package documentation on the first page of the manual?

```
#' flowNet: Mapping the Topology of Single Cell Data
#'
#' Some text...
#'
#' @section Some more text...
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name flowNet
NULL
#> NULL

.datatable.aware <- TRUE
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can, and you have your tools crossed. `devtools` does not influence how base R collates all Rd entries into a pdf.

But I just took one guess at an [older package (`xts`)](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/xts.pdf) by a friend and indeed, it has a first entry ending in "-package":

[image]

So just add an entry `flowNew-package` (via `roxygen2`) and you should be good.

Here is another example from [a package of mine](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf):

[image]